# Entity Framework performance issue while looping with more record

Tags: entity-framework

I have employee details of more than 4000 employees. While retrieving those rows, I am faced with performance issues due to the looping. So what can I do to improve performance?

This is the looping I mentioned:

```
List<EmployeesEntityObject> lstEmployee = new List<EmployeesEntityObject>();

foreach (var item in lst)
{
           EmployeesEntityObject obj = new EmployeesEntityObject();
           obj.EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID;
           obj.EmployeeName = item.EmployeeName;       
           lstEmployee.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: What is `lst` in your `foreach` loop??

Comment: lst is a generic list where i kept 4000 records. using linq query i will retrieve that record.

Comment: So what is slow? Filling that `lst` list with 4000 records? Creating those 4000 `EmployeeEntityObject` instances?

Comment: that is loop is executing 4000 time...

Comment: so it is slow. is there any other solution for that....

Comment: What does the constructor of `EmployeesEntityObject` do? Are you initializing a lot of internal variables? Possibly reaching out to other data sources? That seems like the only operation that *could* take a bit longer...

Answer (score 0):

You could try and see what happens when you completely "linqify" your code:

```
var lstEmployee = lst.Select(emp => new EmployeesEntityObject
                                   {
                                       EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID,
                                       EmployeeName = item.EmployeeName
                                   }).ToList();
```

But as marc_s says, there is no apparent cause for any performance issues in your code. Unless, as said, the constructor and/or the setters of the properties conceal time-consuming code. Both of which, by the way, would not be recommendable.